# WooCommerce is displaying Products from different categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am assisting with my first WooCommerce site and I am stumped.

This site has divided products into Parent and Child categories. When I select a Child category, I should only see Products in that specific category, yet I see its siblings.

Example: This link should only display 8 kw generators. It shows all generators.
https://merequipment.host/product-category/bollard-marine-generators/8kw/

The 104 kw generator displays even though the only category it is in is 104kw.

Each product category has a display type of "Products" saved.

Is this the expected behavior with WooCommerce? If not, is there a fix or somewhere I should be looking? Thank you.

UPDATE 5/24/2018: This ended up being a permission problem. Admin users were seeing products on this page that users were not.

Comment: All I see on the link you posted is a single product, which is in fact a 8kw generator.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. It turned out to be that the logged in user sees the data incorrectly, whereas the non-logged in user sees the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a permission problem. Admin users were seeing products on this page that users were not.